# Why is the motherboard temperature is high when idle , but is normal under Windows?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, lenovo, fan, temperature

I have a Lenovo y50-70 with the following specs:

- CPU: Intel® Core™ i7-4720HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz × 8
- Graphics: Nvidia GeForce GTX 960M and Intel HD Graphics 4600

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 beside Windows 10 in UEFI mode with SecureBoot disabled. Then I have installed the latest Nvidia driver `nvidia-367` and there is no graphics issues, but the temperature of the motherboard is high comparing it with Windows and reaches 60 - 65 C when idle:

[image: Psensor temps]

The temperature in Windows is normally 50 C and below when idle ( I tested it) and there is no fan noise , but in Ubuntu it reaches 60 - 65 when idle.

What did I try so far?

- I have removed `nvidia-367` and installed `nvidia-364` instead.
- I am now using the Intel graphics driver. I switched to it using
  `sudo prime-select intel`.
- I have installed TLP to see if it will fix my problem.
- I have installed CPU-Freq too.

**Note:** the temp is lower somehow when using nvidia driver (57-59 C).

What should I do? Please tell me if you need more info? Thanks

Comment: @wafie-ali I rejected your edit because overusing bold makes things hard to read. Bolding terms is superfluous anyway.

Comment: @wjandrea I accepted many over-bolded edits myself but moved to your camp after the fifth one.